# Реализция Backbone + Yii2. Роли пользователей

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Имеется API на `Yii2 framework.` с ролями пользователей RBAC.
На данный момент пишется Frontend сайта на `Backbone.js`.
По задумке сайта, у каждой роли пользователя своя страница отображения  и данные.
Но у каждой роли выводимые данные значительно разные, и так же разная разметка страницы, выводимые виджеты и т.д.

**Вопрос:** допустим в backbone.js есть общая страница аутентификации пользователя `/#auth`, каким способом мне подргужать необходимые данные в зависимости от возвращаемой роли пользователя?

**Предполагаемый мой ответ:** разместить файлы frontend'a backbone.js внутри фреймворка yii2. Страницу авторизации оставь на GUI Yii2 со страницей `/auth`, определять какую роль использует данный пользователь и уже от ответа загружать необходимый модуль/контроллер который регендит index.view файл - в котором уже подружается single-page backbone. Это решит проблему, как использовать разные роли. Для каждой роли будет свое приложенение на backbone.
Окей.. но если этот вариант жизнеспособен - идет аутентификация на yii2, после чего система перенаправляет меня на нужный action и загружается backbone.
Как мне загрузить сами модели и коллекции данными от API сервера?
Вроде как через yii2 я аутентифицирован, но backbone обо мне ничего не знает?!
Помогите додуматься?! как лучше все это сделать?